# Вывести пользователя, который состоит в большинстве групп Linux

Tags: c++, linux, c, консоль

Нужна команда\программа для вывода пользователя состоящего в большинстве групп на Linux.
Если такой команды не существует,  то как сделать ее программу на C?

Все что я смог это `getent group`

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: читаете `/etc/passwd` с именами пользователей, у каждого пользователя интересуетесь его группами с помощью `groups _user_` и считаете их количество

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for user in `cut /etc/passwd -d : -f 1`; 
do 
  echo -n "$user "
  groups $user | sed -e 's/.*: //' |wc -w
done \
  | sort -k 2 -n -r \
  | head -1
```

Извлекаете список пользователей из `/etc/passwd`: команда `cut /etc/passwd -d : -f 1` разбивает каждую строку на колонки двоеточиями и выводит первую колонку.

Затем для каждого пользователя извлекаете список групп: `groups $user`
Команда выводит в формате `user : group1 group2 ...`, поэтому сначала `sed -e 's/.*: //` отрезает часть `user :` , затем `wc -w` подсчитывает количество слов `group1`, `group2` и т.д.

Благодаря `echo "$user "` цикл печатает список

```
root 1
daemon 1
bin 1
sys 1
sync 1
saned 2
...
```

и так далее

`sort -k 2 -n -r` сортирует по второму столбцу (число групп) в обратном порядке - строка с самым большим числом групп будет первой

`head -1` печатает первую строку.

Answer (score 0):

Поискав интернет нашел нужный мне ответ и написал код который выполняет эту задачу.

```
import os
os.system("for user in $(awk -F: '{print $1}' /etc/passwd); do groups $user; done > users.txt")
users, usersList = open("users.txt", "r"), []
for i in users:
    temp = i.split(':')
    tmp = temp[1].split(' ')
    tmp.pop(0)
    usersList.append([temp[0], tmp])
max, maxindex = 0, 0
for i in range(len(usersList)):
    if len(usersList[i][1]) > max:maxindex = i
print('Пользователь ' + usersList[maxindex][0] + 'состоит в ' + str(len(usersList[maxindex][1])) + ' группах')
print('Группы: ' + ' '.join(usersList[maxindex][1]))
```

Comment: В вопросе C, в ответе Python, странно

Comment: Да)))). Просто питон мне ближе всего поэтому на нем и написал. Теперь пытаюсь на С\С++ такое же сделать